# Hide Panel in a datalist with Linkbutton and C# and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, hide, panel, datalist

I'm a new programmer, so any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

I have a datalist containing a link button that displays a row of data.  The linkbutton, when clicked, should unhide a panel that contains a datalist (also containing a linkbutton), that displays more detailed information.  The problem that I am having is that when I click on the summary linkbutton it will not fire the javascript to hide or show the details panel.  I'm not getting any exceptions, my program builds and runs, so I'm not sure why the javascript won't fire. FYI, the DBClass and DbClass object are in-house classes, they work fine. Here is my code:

```
using System;
usingSystem.Collections;
usingSystem.Configuration;
usingSystem.Data;
usingSystem.Linq;
usingSystem.Web;
usingSystem.Web.Security;
usingSystem.Web.UI;
usingSystem.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
usingSystem.Web.UI.WebControls;
usingSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
usingSystem.Xml.Linq;
usingDBClass;


namespaceTimeLogging.pages
{
  publicpartialclassdbEntry:System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    QueryClassqc=newQueryClass();

  protectedvoidPage_Load(objectsender,EventArgse)
  {
    bindDlReportProjSum_devSummary();
  }

  //getsthelinkbuttonattributefortheemployeeidsothatitcanbeboundtothedatalist
protectedvoiddlReportProjSum_devSummary_OnItemDataBound(objectsender,DataListItemEventArgse)
{
  if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
    || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
  {
    DataListnestedDataList=(DataList)e.Item.FindControl("dlReportProjSum_devDetail");
    LinkButtonlinkbtn=(LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbReportProjSum_devSummary");
    bindDlReportProjSum_devDetail(nestedDataList,linkbtn.Attributes["empid"]);
    //Panelpan=(Panel)e.Item.FindControl("panReportProjSum_devDetail");
  }
}

//hidesthedevedetailpanelonlinkbutttonclick
protectedvoiddlReportProjSum_devSummary_OnItemCommand(objectsender,DataListCommandEventArgse){

LinkButtonlb=(LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbReportProjSum_devSummary");
Panelpan=(Panel)e.Item.FindControl("panReportProjSum_devDetail");
}

//thedatalistthatshowsasummaryofeachemployeewhohasworkedonaproject
protectedvoidbindDlReportProjSum_devSummary(){
DbClassdb=newDbClass();
DataTabledt=newDataTable();
stringsqlString=@"selectname,empid,sum(actualtime)astotal
fromTime_logging_vwProjDevDetail
whereprojid=1
groupbyempid,name";
db.OpenConnection();
db.Execute(sqlString);
dt=db.GetData.Table;
dlReportProjSum_devSummary.DataSource=dt;
dlReportProjSum_devSummary.DataBind();
db.CloseConnection();
db.Dispose();
}



//bindthenesteddatalistinthedevSummaryOnItemDataBoundevent
privatevoidbindDlReportProjSum_devDetail(DataListdl,stringdevEmpid)
{
DbClassdb=newDbClass();
DataTabledt=newDataTable();
stringsqlString=string.Format(@"selectDAYOF,ESTTIME,ACTUALTIME,NOTES,TASK
fromtime_logging_resourceswhere
projid=1andempid={0}",devEmpid);
db.OpenConnection();
db.Execute(sqlString);
dt=db.GetData.Table;
dl.DataSource=dt;
dl.DataBind();

db.CloseConnection();
db.Dispose();
}



////whenthedeveloperssummaryoftotalhoursonaprojectisclicked
protectedvoidlbReportProjSum_devSummary_Click(objectsender,EventArgse)
{
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"Javascript","HidePanel()",true);

}

}
}

ASPXpage////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


<%@PageLanguage="C#"AutoEventWireup="true"CodeBehind="dbEntry.aspx.cs"Inherits="TimeLogging.pages.dbEntry"%>

<%@RegisterAssembly="AjaxControlToolkit"Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"TagPrefix="asp"%>

<!DOCTYPEhtmlPUBLIC"-//W3C//DTDXHTML1.0Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<htmlxmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<headrunat="server">
<title>UntitledPage</title>
<linkhref="../css/Main.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"/>

<scripttype="text/javascript"language="javascript">
functionHidePanel()
{
alert("hello");
varpanel=document.getElementById('panReportProjSum_devDetail');
if(panel.style.display=='none')
{
panel.style.display='block';
}
else
{
panel.style.display='none';
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<formid="form1"runat="server">

<asp:ToolkitScriptManagerID="ToolkitScriptManager1"runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div>
<asp:PanelID="panMainReportsHolder"runat="server">

<asp:DataListID="dlReportProjSum_devSummary"runat="server"RepeatDirection="Vertical"
ShowFooter="False"ShowHeader="False"OnItemDataBound="dlReportProjSum_devSummary_OnItemDataBound"
OnItemCommand="dlReportProjSum_devSummary_OnItemCommand">
<HeaderTemplate>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<div>
<asp:LinkButtonID="lbReportProjSum_devSummary"OnClick="lbReportProjSum_devSummary_Click"
runat="server"empid='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"empid")%>'name='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"name")%>'
total='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"total")%>'CssClass="developerSummaryLinkButton"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"name")%>'stotalhoursspentdevelopingtheproject:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"total")%>

</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:PanelID="panReportProjSum_devDetail"runat="server">

<asp:DataListID="dlReportProjSum_devDetail"runat="server"RepeatDirection="Vertical"
ShowFooter="False"ShowHeader="False">
<HeaderTemplate>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<div>
<asp:LinkButtonID="LinkButton1"CssClass="developerDetailLinkButton"runat="server"
Enabled="false">Dateworked:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"dayof")%>task:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"task")%>numberofhoursworked:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"actualtime")%>anynotes:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"notes")%>
</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</asp:Panel>


</div>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wire up your Linkbutton1 to fire the Javascript event. You can do this using the OnClientClick attribute like so:

```
<asp:LinkButtonID="LinkButton1"CssClass="developerDetailLinkButton"runat="server" Enabled="false" onclientclick="HidePanel();return false;"/>
```

The Return False prevents it from calling the server side event set in onclick (if there is one).

Read more about onclientclick here[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, John MC.  I tried it out and it did get my javascript to fire.  The problem now is that the JavaScript can't find the panel object.  the panel is in a datalist and I believe that the call to the javascript must come from the code behind because the panel is only accessible before and during the binding of the datalist.   I need to find out why the linkbutton's "OnCick" event is not firing the JavaScript, but I don't understand the life-cycles of the page and controls well enough to debug this.

Comment: Depending on the .NET version and other settings, 'panReportProjSum_devDetail' may not be the client ID you need to use (earlier versions of .NET add things like 'ct100_' before the id to help avoid naming collisions). Instead, in the HidePanel() function, you might want to try something like: varpanel=document.getElementById('<%= panReportProjSum_devDetail.ClientID %>');

Comment: Why do you need Javascript to hide the panel? Could you not just do this when the page is loading (PreRender event)? You can programmatically set the style=display:none in the code behind. Don't use Visible=false